# BigQuery Data Transfer Service Error for Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-data-transfer

I am trying to use the BigQuery Data Transfer Service by Google Cloud Platform to bring in my data from Cloud SQL (mysql instance) to BigQuery. I have enrolled the data source on the marketplace portal. Also I am using a Public IP for my mysql instance. I have also added Fivetran IP to the list of authorized connections and also created a fivetran user in mysql to access the cloud SQL db. Still, the connection to source fails without any proper error.

Error message: 
Enable a third-party data connection in BigQuery

You're creating a DTS connector with a third-party data source. Below is the agreement that you need to accept:
By clicking the Accept Agreement button, you grant the Fivetran-managed Service Account read/write access to the BigQuery data set data_transfer_test_ae1 and you understand that BigQuery will only respect the data location (asia-east1) once the data is in data_transfer_test_ae1. You also acknowledge that Google will send your email address and the fields in the form to Fivetran as part of this transfer.

[object ErrorResponse]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzBoP.png)

Comment: While waiting for an answer here, it wouldn't hurt to create a bug on BigQuery to be helped by Google Support: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Hi, I raised the issue on Google Support